# Search for Track using Spotify API add in Album name and Artist name

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, spotify

Working on a quick project to search for a music track in Spotify...  You add your track name into text area and produce a list of matching Track Id's with Artist Names and Album Name + Artwork... Below is example of the code that I have working on so far...  Stuck getting the Album Name / Album Image and the Artist Name...

Example - that I was using was:
Track: All of me
Results should be Artist: John Legend
Track ID is correct: 3U4isOIWM3VvDubwSI3y7a

Shows as the first one....

http://jsfiddle.net/61f64ccq/2/

Also (Updated this bit...)

http://jsfiddle.net/UT7bQ/212/
    {{name}} - {{this.artists.name}}
Trying to add code for the Handlebar.js for getting the Artists name from the .JSON data...

Below for the first example....

Using pure JS / Handlebar.js and HTML5.... Any help would be great... Did try {{artists.name}} but nothing was happening...

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Search for a Track - Spotify</h1>
<form id="search-form">
<input type="text" id="query" value="" class="form-control" />
<input type="submit" id="search" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
</div>
<script id="results-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each tracks.items}}
<div >{{id}} -         
<br /> {{name}} <br/></div>
// Issue - Image
<div style="border:1px solid red; background-image:url({{images.2.url}})" data-album-id="{{id}}" class="cover"></div>
// Issue - Artist Name and Album Name
<div style="border:1px solid green; "> Artist name = {  } -  Album name = { } </div>
```

Part of the Javascript code -

```
<script>
var templateSource = document.getElementById('results-template').innerHTML,
template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource),
resultsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('results'),
playingCssClass = 'playing',
audioObject = null;
var fetchTracks = function (albumId, callback) {
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/' + albumId,
success: function (response) {
callback(response);
}
});
};
var searchAlbums = function (query) {
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search',
data: {
q: query,
type: 'track'
// Gets the track - search query
},
success: function (response) {
resultsPlaceholder.innerHTML = template(response);
}
});
};
// This was for playing the Track in your window...  Not working in the Track format...
results.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var target = e.target;
if (target !== null && target.classList.contains('cover')) {
if (target.classList.contains(playingCssClass)) {
audioObject.pause();
} else {
if (audioObject) {
audioObject.pause();
}
fetchTracks(target.getAttribute('data-album-id'), function (data) {
audioObject = new Audio(data.tracks.items[0].preview_url);
audioObject.play();
target.classList.add(playingCssClass);
audioObject.addEventListener('ended', function () {
target.classList.remove(playingCssClass);
});
audioObject.addEventListener('pause', function () {
target.classList.remove(playingCssClass);
});
});
}
}
});
document.getElementById('search-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
searchAlbums(document.getElementById('query').value);
}, false);
</script>
```

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what i changed and added a Fiddle example - with example on Handlebars getting the Album info in the right format - Image / Artist, Album Type and Album Name....  Hopefully useful to others....

http://jsfiddle.net/61f64ccq/4/

```
<script id="results-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each tracks.items}}
<div >{{id}} -         
<br /> {{name}} <br/></div>
<div style="border:1px solid red; background-image:url({{album.images.2.url}})" data-album-id="{{id}}" class="cover"></div>
<div style="border:1px solid green; "> Artist name = {{artists.0.name}} </div>
<div style="border:1px solid green; "> Album Type = {{album.album_type}} </div>
<div style="border:1px solid green; "> Album name = {{album.name}} </div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Thanks to everyone looking at this - has now been fixed...  Cheers Simon